# How to flicker an image-object for a couple of seconds after a certain time?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

With a power-up (here with an `onclick` on the canvas) I make the paddle longer for a couple of seconds before it's getting small again. In some games you see that after a couple of seconds the long paddle begins to flicker and then comes to his normal size again. How do you do that?

**This is my JavaScript code:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mijnCanvas");
var mijnObject = canvas.getContext("2d");

var afbeelding = new Image();
var balkX = (canvas.width/2)-50;
var balkY = canvas.height-40;

var balX = canvas.width/2;
var balY = canvas.height-50;
var radius = 10;
var balNaarX = 5;
var balNaarY = 5;

function makenBalkKort() {
    mijnObject.drawImage(afbeelding, balkX, balkY, afbeelding.width, afbeelding.height);
}
afbeelding.src = "Afbeeldingen/BrickSmasher_Balk_Kort.png";

function makenBal() {
    mijnObject.beginPath();
    var mijnBalGradient = mijnObject.createRadialGradient(balX, balY, 0, balX, balY, 8);
    mijnBalGradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
    mijnBalGradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
    mijnObject.fillStyle = mijnBalGradient;
    mijnObject.strokeStyle = ("black");
    mijnObject.arc(balX, balY, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    mijnObject.fill();
    mijnObject.stroke();
    mijnObject.closePath(); 
}

function tekenenObjecten() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    makenBal();
    makenBalkKort();

    setTimeout(function() {
        if(balX+balNaarX > canvas.width-radius || balX+balNaarX < radius) {
            balNaarX = -balNaarX;
        }
        if(balY+balNaarY < radius) {
            balNaarY = -balNaarY;
        }
        else if(balY+balNaarY > balkY-radius) {
            if(balX > balkX && balX < balkX + afbeelding.width) {
                balNaarY = -balNaarY;
            }
            else {
                alert("Game over");
            }
        }
        balX += balNaarX;
        balY += balNaarY;
    }, 1000);
}
setInterval(tekenenObjecten, 20);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function LinksOfRechts() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(balkX, balkY, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var balkNaarX = 10;
    var code = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if(code == 37) {
        if(balkX > 0) {
            balkX -= balkNaarX;
        }
    }
    else if(code == 39) {
        if(balkX < canvas.width-afbeelding.width) {
            balkX += balkNaarX;
        }
    }
    mijnObject.drawImage(afbeelding, balkX, balkY, afbeelding.width, afbeelding.height);
});

canvas.addEventListener("click", function balkLangMaken() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(balkX, balkY, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    afbeelding.src = "Afbeeldingen/BrickSmasher_Balk_Lang.png";
    setTimeout(function() {
        mijnObject.clearRect(balkX, balkY, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        afbeelding.src = "Afbeeldingen/BrickSmasher_Balk_Kort.png";
    }, 3000);
});
```

**This is my HTML code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BrickSmasher</title>
<style>
    canvas {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block; 
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="mijnCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
  <script src="BrickSmasher.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the images:

[image: BrickSmasher_Balk_Kort]

[image: BrickSmasher_Balk_Lang]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use `requestAnimationFrame` to run a short flicker animation loop**

Start with these variables:

```
// the x,y of the flickering paddle
var flickerX=50;
var flickerY=50;
// the starting time of the flickering animation
var flickerStart=0;
// how long the flickering will continue (2000ms==2seconds)
var flickerDuration=2000;
// a flag indicating if the paddle currently [shows|doesn't show]
var flickerIsOn=true;
// the next time at which the flicker will reverse (show <--> noShow)
var nextTime=0;
```

Then in the animation loop you...

- Wait a short duration. `requestAnimationFrame` automatically sends in a current timestamp that you can use to calculate if the short duration has elapsed.
- Calculate a new short random "flicker" duration.
- Flip the flickerIsOn indicating if the paddle [shows|doesn't show].
- If the flickerIsOn flag is true, then drawImage the paddle. If the flickerIsOn flag is false, then `clearRect` the paddle area.
- If the animation duration hasn't elapsed, request another animation loop. If the flicker animation is done, redraw the small paddle.

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

$('#flicker').prop('disabled',true);
var flickerX=50;
var flickerY=50;
var flickerStart=0;
var flickerDuration=2000;
var flickerIsOn=true;
var nextTime=0;
var paddle=new Image();
paddle.onload=start;
paddle.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/paddle.png";
var paddleSmall=new Image();
paddleSmall.onload=start;
paddleSmall.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/paddleSmall.png";
var imgCount=2;
function start(){
    if(!--imgCount){return;}
    ctx.drawImage(paddle,flickerX,flickerY);
    $('#flicker').on('click',function(){
        startFlicker(flickerX,flickerY);
    });
    $('#flicker').prop('disabled',false);
}
//
function startFlicker(){
    flickerStart=performance.now();
    flickIsOn=true;
    nextTime=0;
    requestAnimationFrame(flickerPaddle);
}
//
function flickerPaddle(time){
    // wait 
    if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(flickerPaddle);return;}
    // calculate a short random duration
    nextTime=time+(50+Math.random()*150);
    // flip the flicker flag
    flickerIsOn=!flickerIsOn;
    // if flickerIsOn, draw the paddle
    if(flickerIsOn){
        ctx.drawImage(paddle,flickerX,flickerY);
    }else{
        ctx.clearRect(flickerX,flickerY,paddle.width,paddle.height);
    }
    // continue animating until flickerDuration is reached 
    if(time-flickerStart<flickerDuration){
        requestAnimationFrame(flickerPaddle);
    }else{
        ctx.clearRect(flickerX,flickerY,paddle.width,paddle.height);
        ctx.drawImage(paddleSmall,flickerX,flickerY);
    }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=flicker>Flicker randomly for 2 seconds</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That looks very impressive and the right thing I want. The only problem is that I'm not familiar with jQuery, I honestly know nothing about jQuery. If it's not too much asked, could you send the same thing in Javascript code. If you do that, I will be eternally grateful to you.

Comment: @KevinN **About the jQuery:** The jQuery is only there for the demo-button and your app doesn't need the button at all. You just need the `startFlicker` and `flickerPaddle` functions. ;-)

Comment: I want to thank you for your help. This code will help me to go further with my mini-game in making.